# Strange behavior of EOFException

Tags: java, file-io, stream, eofexception

I have some simple class that is `DataInputStream` stream to read from file.

I have surrounded this stream with `EOFException` try-catch block.

It has some strange behavior coz sometimes it throws EOFException into text that is read.

Output to console:

```
"The vessel was in as good condition as I am, and as, I hope
you ar#End of streame#, M. Morrel, and this day and a half was lost from
pure whim, for the pleasure of going ashore, and nothing
else."
```

I couldn't figure out what is cause of this strange behavior...

Here is code snippet:

```
public class FormattedMemoryInput {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        boolean done = false;    
        try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                BufferedInputFile.read("./gutenberg/cristo.txt").getBytes()));) {

            while (!done) {
                System.out.print((char) in.readByte());
            }
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            System.err.println("#End of stream#");
        }
    }
}
```

It uses static method `BufferedInputFile.read()` to read first 500 lines:

```
public class BufferedInputFile {

    // Throw exceptions to console:
    public static String read(String filename) throws IOException {

        // Reading input by lines:
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s;
        int i = 0;

        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null && (i < 500)) {
            sb.append(s + "\n");
            i++;
        }

        in.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

- ***Why EOFException is thrown into text?***

**Solution:**

It was at adding one line:

```
while (!done) {
    System.out.print((char) in.readByte());
    System.out.flush(); // this one
}
```

Comment: If you are only interested in bytes, there is no need for DataInputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out` is buffered by default; `System.err` isn't. If you redirect one of the output streams, either in your program or from the shell, you should see the output in the expected order. You can force `System.out` to print its output by calling `System.out.flush();`; try inserting that at the end of your `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're getting an `EOFException` because you're reading forever - you never change the value of `done`.

The reason it's appearing in the middle of the text instead of at the end is that you're using `System.err` to print in the exceptional case, and `System.out` to print the main text. Those are separate streams, flushed separately. If you flush `System.out` before writing to `System.err`, I suspect you'll see the main text before the error message. (Note that you're using `println` on `System.err`, which will flush automatically, but just `print` on `System.out`, which won't.)

There are various other things I'd change about the code - particularly the use of `String.getBytes()` without specifying an encoding - but assuming I've understood your question correctly, the difference in streams is the reason you're looking for.